# Python convert list with parentheses at both ends to a normal list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, matplotlib

My dataframe has many lists. When try to plot them, I found that each got a parentheses at both ends. How to remove it and convert them to a normal string.

My code:

```
df = 
        xdat             ydat
0   [0.5,2.2,3.4]   [4.5,9.2,1.4] 
1   [2.5,3.2,3.6]   [7.5,6.2,4.4]
2   [4.5,2.9,3.7]   [8.5,3.2,8.4]

for i,r in df.iterrows():
    print(type(r['xdat'])
    #plt.plot(r['xdat'],r['ydat'])
#plt.show()
```

Present output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

I found that each list got parentheses at both ends as given below when I tried to plot them. But, the original data frame has no parentheses at both ends.

```
'[0.5,2.2,3.4]'
```

So, how to remove the unwanted parentheses seen at both ends of the list?

Comment: just strip them away with `r[1:-1]`

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe there is something a pythonic way of solving it might be there?

Comment: This is the cleanest solution. You could also `eval` and then `join` the elements with `', '` which is way messier.

Answer (score 0):

If all your lists are flat you might do:

```
x = '[0.5,2.2,3.4]'
y = x.strip('[]')
print(y)  # 0.5,2.2,3.4
```

Comment: Will it remove just the end `'` parentheses only ? or the list brackets as well?

Comment: I tried this in my above code with `print(type(r['xdat'].strip('[]'))` but it still says the list as string type.

Comment: @Mainland: `.strip` is method of `str` and it does return `str` with jettisoned leading and trailing `chars`, so `'[[5]]'.strip('[]')` result in `5`, whilst `'[1,[2],3]'.strip('[]')` result in `1,[2],3`

Comment: Ok. Got it. Now I tried this `plt.plot(r['xact'].strip('[]'),r['yact'].strip('[]'))` but got the following error. `'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c) ValueError: Unrecognized character 9 in format string`

Comment: I got the following when I did the `.strip([])` answer `'0.5,2.2,3.4'`. It removed `[` but the parentheses still appear here?

Comment: I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list  Thanks